# PHP/CodeIgniter recursive function to return records from a self referencial sql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is really challenging for me. I am trying to build a small app that allows users to organise their files into folders and sub-folders. I am using 1 MySQL table for the folders with a field (parent_id) to reference  the parent folder  in the same table.

I am trying to create a function that returns an array with all the child-folders for a specific folder_id, below is my attempt, this only returns the first level child folders [this code wrong & i am completely stuck!!].

```
private function child_folders($folder_id,$user_id,$folders = array()) {
 $query = this->db->get_where("folders",array("parent_id"=>$folder_id,"user_id"=>$user_id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
       foreach ($query->result_array() as $folder) {
          array_push($folders, $folder);
       }
        return $this->child_folders($folder["folder_id"],$user_id,$folders);
    } else {
         return $folders;
    }
}
```

MySQL Table

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+---------+
| folder_id | name    | description | datetime            | parent_id | user_id |
+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+---------+
|       170 | 1       | NULL        | 2014-03-28 19:42:02 |         0 |     164 |
|       171 | 1.1     | NULL        | 2014-03-28 19:42:57 |       170 |     164 |
|       172 | 1.2     | NULL        | 2014-03-28 19:43:07 |       170 |     164 |
|       173 | 1.3     | NULL        | 2014-03-28 19:43:19 |       170 |     164 |
|       174 | 1.3.1   | NULL        | 2014-03-28 19:44:13 |       173 |     164 |
|       175 | 1.3.2   | NULL        | 2014-03-28 19:44:29 |       173 |     164 |
|       176 | 1.3.3   | NULL        | 2014-03-28 19:45:06 |       173 |     164 |
|       177 | 1.3.3.1 | NULL        | 2014-03-28 19:45:33 |       176 |     164 |
|       178 | 2       | NULL        | 2014-03-28 20:55:33 |         0 |     164 |
|       179 | 2.1     | NULL        | 2014-03-28 20:56:09 |       178 |     164 |
|       180 | 2.2     | NULL        | 2014-03-28 20:58:03 |       178 |     164 |
|       181 | 2.3     | NULL        | 2014-03-28 20:58:19 |       178 |     164 |
|       182 | 2.1.1   | NULL        | 2014-03-28 20:59:40 |       179 |     164 |
|       183 | 2.1.2   | NULL        | 2014-03-28 21:00:05 |       179 |     164 |
+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below little change in your function line.

```
$folders = array();

private function child_folders($folder_id,$user_id,&$folders) {
$query = this->db->get_where("folders",array("parent_id"=>$folder_id,"user_id"=>$user_id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
       foreach ($query->result_array() as $folder) {
          array_push($folders, $folder);
       }
        return $this->child_folders($folder["folder_id"],$user_id,$folders);
    } else {
         return $folders;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error:

Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference

Comment: You are right.Now,I found your problem.
It is in below lines:

foreach ($query->result_array() as $folder) 
{
  array_push($folders, $folder);
}
return $this->child_folders($folder["folder_id"],$user_id,$folders);

after completion of your loop only last $folder["folder_id"] is only passing...
it is mistake.

Now let me know what you want in your OUTPUT actually.

Comment: The current code returns first level sub-folders. I want to return all child folders. I think as soon as my $query->num_rows() > 0, the function terminates and this happens when I get to the end of 1 of the folders, I need to be able to still look for other possible child folders. This is a complex problem. 

If I adopt manual nested loops, then I will need to have 10 of them, since the folders can only be 10 levels deep at this time, but I think a recursive function can be a better solution, so that in future if the depth of folders changes, I will not need to add more nested loops manually.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work by modifying my original function, but the problem is the amount of DB queries because I query the DB for each child folder to get all the children, but I think the solution for that would be a SQL query that will return the child folders as a structured list.

```
private function _child_folders($folder_id,$user_id,$folders = array()) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where("folders",array("parent_id"=>$folder_id,"user_id"=>$user_id)); 
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $folder) {
        array_push($folders, $folder);
        $folders =& $this->_child_folders($folder["folder_id"],$user_id,$folders);
    }
    return $folders;
}
```

running $this->_child_folders(178,164); gives me this result, which is what I have been looking for.

```
array(
   [0] =>array(
       ['folder_id'] =>179
       ['name'] =>2.1
       ['description'] =>
       ['datetime'] =>'2014-03-28 20:56:09'
       ['parent_id'] =>178
       ['user_id'] =>164
  )
   [1] => array(
       ['folder_id'] =>182
       ['name'] =>2.1.1
       ['description'] =>
       ['datetime'] =>'2014-03-28 20:59:40'
       ['parent_id'] =>179
       ['user_id'] => 164
   )
    [2] =>array(
       ['folder_id'] =>183
       ['name'] =>2.1.2
       ['description'] =>
       ['datetime'] =>'2014-03-28 21:00:05'
       ['parent_id'] =>179
       ['user_id'] =>164
   )
    [3] =>array(
      ['folder_id'] =>180
      ['name'] =>2.2
      ['description'] =>
      ['datetime'] =>'2014-03-28 20:58:03'
      ['parent_id'] =>178
      ['user_id'] =>164
   )
   [4] =>array(
      ['folder_id'] =>181
      ['name'] =>2.3
      ['description'] =>
      ['datetime'] =>'2014-03-28 20:58:19'
      ['parent_id'] =>178
      ['user_id'] =>164
    )
)
```